# Preventing a const member function from changing a member array

Tags: c++, constants

Apparently, a const member function is still allowed to change data that the class member are pointing to. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass();
  int getSomething() const;
private:
  int* data;
};

// ... data = new int[10];, or whatever

int MyClass::getSomething() const
{
  data[4] = 3; // this is allowed, even those the function is const
  return data[4];
}
```

I'd prefer if this was not allowed. How should I define "data" so that "getSomething() const" isn't allowed to change it? (but so that non-const functions are allowed to change it.) Is there some kind of "best practice" for this? Perhaps std::vector?

Comment: Yes, it turns out that const member functions aren't as useful as you thought.

Comment: @David: It can be made useful, only if he uses `std::vector<int>` instead of `int*`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a `const` member function, the type of `data` changes from `int*` to `int *const`:

```
int * const data;
```

which means, it's the pointer which is `const` in the const member function, not the data itself the pointer points to. So you cannot do the following:

```
data = new int[100]; //error
```

as it's attempting to change the pointer itself which is const, hence disallowed, but the following is allowed:

```
data[0] = 100; //ok
```

Because changing *the content* doesn't change *the pointer*. `data` points to same memory location.

If you use `std::vector<int>`, then you can achieve what you want. In fact, vector solves this problem, along with the memory management issues, therefor use it:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
  MyClass();
  int getSomething() const;
private:
  std::vector<int> data;
};

MyClass::MyClass() : data(10) {}  //vector of size 10

int MyClass::getSomething() const
{
  data[4] = 3; // compilation error - this is what you wanted.
  return data[4];
}
```

Avoid non-RAII design as much as you can. RAII is superior solution to memory management issues. Here, with it, you achieve what you want. Read this:

- [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)

Comment: @quasiverse: Yes. I explained that bit also, as to how to achieve what he wants to.

Comment: I defend myself with the fact that you edited it after my comment. Moving on, +1 for answer. -1 since I have no votes left.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do what you want. Your const member function can't change the value of data (the address it points to), but there is nothing about not changing the contents it points to as you have already noticed. Using a `std::vector` would help, since within a const member function you would actually have a const vector, not being able to call any of its mutable functions.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you should use std::vector is actually because you want to store a collection of ints, and not an int pointer, so why not use it?

It would also solve your const'ness issue.

Here's how it works: declaring a method const will make all class members const. In your case, that means that in the method scope, your member `data` will become a constant pointer to an int. That means you can change the int (also meaning array members) as long as `data` points to the same location. Using `std::vector`, data would become a const `std::vector`, on which you could only call const functions. So yes, you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: I agree. I do want to store a collection of ints, and I think vector would be the right choice - however, this particular code is inherited. ie. I didn't write it. So I'm not certain that it's worth the bother of changing all of the int* to vector<int>...

Comment: Regardless... Legacy code is not always good, you should talk to whoever is managing the code and plead to change it.